# Intersection between CSL and CFL?

Tags: regular-languages, automata, context-free, context-sensitive

I am trying to find a proof of A ∩ B where A is a **CSL** and B is a **CFL**.
Also I know that CFL is a strict subset of CSL. Does that mean that their intersection will give CFL. I am stuck

Comment: Welcome to the site! Hint: If $B\subseteq A$, you can tell what $A\cap B$ is, right?

Comment: @RickDecker That's what I understood first, but I think OP wanted to say that the set of CFL is a strict subset of the set of CSL (and not that $B\subset A$).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the general case, the intersection between a context-sensitive language and a context-free language is context-sensitive.

See [this post](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/141538/what-is-the-closure-of-context-free-languages-under-finite-intersections) for details.